# Calculating % of the element that's been scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a set of divs. Lets for this example believe they are like this.

```
<body>
    <div id="ignore" data-tag="sections" style="height:20%">
    </div>
    <div id="2" data-tag="sections" style="height:20%">
        Content content content
    </div>
    <div id="3" data-tag="sections" style="height:20%">
        Content content content
    </div>
    <div id="4" data-tag="sections" style="height:20%">
        Content content content
    </div>
    <div id="5" data-tag="sections" style="height:20%">
        Content content content
    </div>
    <div id="end" data-tag="sections" style="height:0%">
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to know which element the user is viewing. Viewing is considered in view when the div hits the top of the page.

I also want to know how far they have scrolled through the current element in relation to the next sibling (as a percentage).

As an added bonus I would like to know how much there is left to scroll of the whole page excluding the top "ignore" div.

Can anyone direct me in the right direction?

This is what I've got but 1) it fires WAY to many times 2) after the first element it fails.

My brain hurts.

```
function get_init_distances(){
    array=[]
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tag="sections"]')
    elems.forEach(function(el){
        array.push({el:el,top:el.getBoundingClientRect().top})
    })
    return array
}

function get_current_el_and_perc(){
    var i = 0
    var start = 0
    var perc = 0
    var old_id = ""
    //loop elements
    array.forEach(function(el){
        if(i !== 0){
            //get perc of completion of first window
            perc = (el.top - (start + window.pageYOffset)) / el.top
            //log
            if(perc > 0 && perc < 1){
                console.log(perc)
                console.log(old_id)
                return
            }
        }
        //set old id and top
        old_id = el.el.id
        start = start + el.top
        i ++
    })
}

var scrolls
window.onload = () => {
    scrolls = get_init_distances()
    document.addEventListener("scroll",get_current_el_and_perc)
}
```

Comment: Would the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) help here?

Comment: I will take a look thanks

Comment: You can take a look at these two links and see which one is the best. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

Comment: @Phix That is perfect by the way, thanks for that. If you want to put it into an answer I'll accept it :)